# Triggering left button click event on browser HTML element - directly from keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, mouse

I desire to open a link I stand on with the mouse (that is, a link that the mouse cursor is situated upon), directly from the keyboard:

Instead me single-clicking the left mouse button to open the link my cursor flies above, I would just hit some **keyboard combo** and a click event will be triggered directly where the mouse cursor is situated at.

I didn't find a way [in this list](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) or in this [SE QA session](https://superuser.com/questions/195419/google-chrome-is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab).

<sub>I don't mean to Focusing on the element with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or to</sub>

```
document.querySelector('#myElement').click()
```

Comment: I'm confused to what it so you are trying to do. Are you asking how to listen for key presses and check for multiple keys/shortcut to then simulate a mouse click on a specific element? If so can you please provide the relevant source code that you are working with and explain your attempt(s). Thank you.

Comment: I tried to edit to better explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following JavaScript code to achieve what you want exactly, **without** modifying your HTML or CSS.

```js
function listenToShortcut(e) {
  // Change the shortcut to what you desire
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 83) {
    e.target.click();
  }
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {
  link.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
  link.style.outline = 'none';
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(me) {
    link.focus();
    link.addEventListener('keydown', listenToShortcut);
  });
  link.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    link.removeEventListener('keydown', listenToShortcut);
  });
});
```

In this example, the shortcut is **`Ctrl + Shift + s`**. You can change it to what you need.

## Explanations

- `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` is a workaround to iterate through all the link elements.
- Setting `tabindex` attribute of each link to `'0'` **allows us to listen to `keydown` event on the link by making the link focusable**.
- Setting `outline` style attribute of each link to `'none'`. prevents an [ugly blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa7tM.png) from appearing around the link when the mouse pointer enters it.
- When the mouse pointer enters the link area, **we focus the link with the
  `focus()` method so we can listen to the `keydown` event on that link**.
  Then we add an event listener that listens to `keydown` event on that
  link.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to attach an event listener on the whole document for mouse moves and capture the target of that element. That way you know which element the mouse is hovering over and then you can `dispatch` a `MouseEvent`.

See the example below (press `G` to simulate a click):

(the CSS is for aesthetics only)

```js
let lastMouseElement;
let lastMouseEvent;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  if (event.target) {
    lastMouseEvent = event;
    lastMouseElement = event.target;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.key.toLowerCase() === 'g') {
    if (lastMouseElement && lastMouseEvent) {
      console.log('simulated click');
      lastMouseElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
        clientX: lastMouseEvent.clientX,
        clientY: lastMouseEvent.clientY,
        screenX: lastMouseEvent.screenX,
        screenY: lastMouseEvent.screenY,
      }));
    }
  }
});


Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container *')).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    element.classList.add('flash');
    setTimeout(() => element.classList.remove('flash'), 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top, .bottom {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.618em;
}

.flash {
  transition: all 200ms;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top">A</div>
    <div class="bottom">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">C</div>
    <div class="bottom">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```